# Swift Playgrounds keeps freezing while tuning the code.

Tags: ios, swift, swift-playground

I am working on a little solution for a Swift playground task but the program freezes. I don't get any errors in the code and it looks like the program not even starts executing the code. Solution anyone.? 
I restarted the program reloaded the page and restarted the iPad.

Comment: Some times Xcdoe was very slow in playgrounds. Wait for some time. And also depends RAM of your Mac.

Comment: I know now that the While loop freezes the program. I worked around it but it is definitely a bug in Swift Playground

Comment: Thats good You found solution. Remember one thing When You ask question Please post your code, then someone can help you. Thanks